# jgGrid Showing wrong Time in DateTime field

Tags: javascript, datetime, jqgrid, datetime-format, jqgrid-formatter

I am using jqGrid in one of my application. In this I have show the date in this `d/m/Y H:m:s`(Ex `01/12/2011 14:59:10`). I am getting format correctly but it show wrong time (at minutes)
like : I am getting date time form database is `01/12/2011 14:59:10` but it showing `01/12/2011 14:12:10`.

this is the jqGrid code:

```
url: "/DigitalJobMonitoring/GetFailedGridData",
datatype: 'json',
mtype: 'Get',
colNames: ['Sr.No', 'Job Name', 'Server Name', 'Status', 'Last Run Time'],
colModel: [
    { key: true, width: 50, resizable: false, name: 'SerialNumber', index: 'SerialNumber', sorttype: 'integer' },
    { key: false, width: 300, resizable: false, name: 'JobName', index: 'JobName', sorttype: 'text' },
    { key: false, width: 100, resizable: false, name: 'ServerName', index: 'ServerName', sorttype: 'text' },
    { key: false, width: 100, resizable: false, name: 'Status', index: 'Status', sorttype: 'text' },
    { key: false, width: 150, resizable: false, name: 'LastRunTime', index: 'LastRunTime', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "d/m/Y H:m:s", newformat: "d/m/Y H:m:s" }, searchoptions: { dataInit: initDateSearch } }],
search: true,
searchOnEnter: true,
pager: '#failedRunningPager',
height: '100%',
caption: 'Failed/Running Jobs',
emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
jsonReader: {
    root: "rows",
    page: "page",
    total: "total",
    records: "records",
    repeatitems: false,
    SerialNumber: "0"
},
```

I have tried with different srcformat`(ISO8601Long`,`UniversalSortableDateTime`,`d/m/Y H:m:s`,`SortableDateTime` etc.) in `formatoptions` but no luck.
find screenshots here. 
date time from data base:

[date time from data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbWat.png)

thanks in advance

Updated :

[Here is the JSON date which returned to server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPu5N.png)

Comment: Which version of jqGtid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Could you include test JSON data returned from `url: "/DigitalJobMonitoring/GetFailedGridData"`? The picture, which you included contain only some data from *your server code*, but it's unclear in which format your server return the data (how it serialize the data).

Comment: i am using version "4.4.4"(<package id="jQuery.jqGrid" version="4.4.4" targetFramework="net45" />). i have added the JSON data returned code please find.

Comment: What you added is *not JSON data*. It's fragment of C# code, where `failedRunningResults` is unclear and the setting of JSON serialization are unclear too. You can use Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox, click Network tab and to reload the grid. You will see HTTP trace. Finding the request to `/DigitalJobMonitoring/GetFailedGridData` and examine HTTP body you will see the exact JSON data, which returns the server.

Comment: jqGrid 4.4.4 is **very old version** (4 years old), which is deprecated since many years ago. If you installed jqGrid from Nuget then you should uninstall [jQuery.jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.jqGrid/) 4.4.4 and install [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/) 4.13.6. New version of jqGrid try to detect some typical formats of Date and parse typically correctly the data returned from ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: i have tried with new version that you suggested(free-jqgrid 4.13.6) but no luck. please find the updated one for JSON date which is returned to server. it is returning date in the form of "/Date(1485158400000)/". i have no idea which srcformat, i need to use to get required date format

Comment: Free jqGrid detects Microsoft Date format `/Date(1485158400000)/` automatically. Please verify your test. You can see on the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/9mz4q1gd/1/ that both ISO8601 and Microsoft Date will be correctly displayed in the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft Date format `/Date(1485158400000)/` will be automatically detected by recent versions of jqGrid. I recommend you uninstall NuGet package [jQuery.jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.jqGrid/) 4.4.4 and install [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/) 4.13.6. jqGrid 4.4.4 is **very old** (4 years old) and it's deprecated since many years.

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/9mz4q1gd/1/ uses [free-jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.6 and the following properties in `colModel`

```
sorttype: "date", formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d/m/Y H:m:s" }
```

You can see that the dates will be correctly parsed, formatted and sorted in both input formats: ISO8601 and Microsoft Date.

**UPDATED:** I see finally your error. You used **wrong format for the minutes** in the date format. You used month instead of minutes. You should fix `newformat: "d/m/Y H:m:s"` to `newformat: "d/m/Y H:i:s"`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/u5Lvepyu/14/

Comment: i had uninstalled jQuery.jqGrid 4.4.4 and have installed free-jqGrid 4.13.6. tried using your demo but still no luck getting same result as before. i have tried by convert datetime field to string, then i am getting correct date and time as like string but in this case sort is getting problem as we con't sort string as like a date.

Comment: @AshokDavuluri: Sorry, but I can't debug the pictures, which you posted. The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/9mz4q1gd/1/, which I included in my answer uses Echo service of JSFiddle: `url: "/echo/json/", datatype: "json", mtype: "POST", postData: { json: JSON.stringify(serverResponse) }`. You can replace `serverResponse` or `JSON.stringify(serverResponse)` with **your data** and modify `colModel` to youth. In the way you can prepare the demo *with your test data* and I could debug it.

Comment: Thanks, but No luck. I have prepared a demo with my JSON data which is returned to server in my application please find it [jsfiddle.net/ashok4004/u5Lvepyu/10/](https://jsfiddle.net/ashok4004/u5Lvepyu/10/) i am not getting Grid in the result tab of JSFiddle. please take my sample data in the demo serverResponse and try to debug and let me know if need any info.

Comment: @AshokDavuluri: To see results in JSFiddle demo you need just click on "External resources" on the left part and to insert all dependent CSS and JavaScript files. The results will be the following https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/u5Lvepyu/12/. It seems good for me. What error you have exacltly?

Comment: @AshokDavuluri: I found finally the reason of your problem: see **UPDATED** part of the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for help.